# C++11: Publisher/Consumer pattern does not finish unless publisher sleeps

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

In C++, I am trying to get a handle for the publisher/consumer pattern using a `condition_variable`. This is loosely the template I have seen online:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

mutex m;
queue<string> que;
condition_variable cond;

void write(string &&msg) {
    unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
    que.push(msg);
    locker.unlock();
    cond.notify_one();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1));
}

void read() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
        cond.wait(locker);
        if (!que.empty()) {
            cout << que.front() << endl;
            que.pop();
        }
        locker.unlock();
    }
}

void publisher(string &msg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        write("Publisher: " + msg + ", " + to_string(i));
}

int main() {

    string msg = "Hello";
    thread pub_thread(publisher, std::ref(msg));

    /* The main thread will print the publisher's messages to cout. */
    read();

    /* Make the main thread wait for the publisher to finish. */
    pub_thread.join(); //
    return 0;
}
```

The thing I do not understand is the `sleep_for` call on the publisher thread. I understand that this is there simply to simulate a "real life" scenario in which the publisher will not be spitting out messages so fast. However, curiously, if I comment out that line, the code does not run to completion. Why is that?

Furthermore, I tried setting the sleep_for time to 0 with the same effect. It seems that the published fundamentally needs to sleep, but I do not understand why. To get more specific, the code should print out 100 messages. If I let the code sleep for 1 ms, then all 100 messages are printed. If I do not, then I only see about 10 messages before the code freezes. It seems like there is a deadlock occurring.

Bonus points if there is a better pattern which avoids having to put the publisher to sleep...

I am aware that in practice you need to have a strategy for stopping the main thread, like a poison pill. I have intentionally omitted this to focus on the present discussion.

### EDIT

Hmmm. If I put in a block to handle spurious wakeup, then that fixes the problem. But that still does not explain why the original code failed.

Here is an improved read function:

```
void read() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
        cond.wait(locker, [&](){ return !que.empty(); });
        cout << que.front() << endl;
        que.pop();
        locker.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: well you hold the same lock for the entire duration of both `read` and `write`, and you loop with `while`, and inside `read`. .It is not guaranteed that they take get to take turns. Especially not within 100 iterations.

Comment: If sleep_for () is not called or set to 0ms, the CPU may be overloaded and block status may persist.
Anyway, with multithreading, you will be overloading 100/8% of the time for one of eight CPUs. ~ 12.5% means 100% load on one CPU.

Comment: This is really dependent on your platform and the details of the scheduler. There's no reason for the consumer to get scheduled as soon as the publisher unlocks, it's very likely to be starved. Even if it wakes, it first tries to re-lock the mutex, and the publisher almost certainly got there first.

Comment: Use the CALLBACK function and EVENT to eliminate the worst of endless circulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the situation when the publisher is publishing faster than the consumer consuming.

When that happens, the consumer will miss `condition_variable` triggers. Remember that `notify` calls do not accumulate.

Change the consumer to consume all available messages once it wakes up:

`if (!que.empty())` → `while (!que.empty())`

Like this:

```
void read() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
        cond.wait(locker);
        while (!que.empty()) {
            cout << que.front() << endl;
            que.pop();
        }
        locker.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your insight that notify calls dont accumulate is correct.

Comment: It definitely, definitely is and always has been. Notification is a transient event. You're supposed to notify the waiter that the protected state has changed, but it's up to you to manage the protected state (the queue in this case) yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems: one is that the publisher is under no obligation to yield to the reader - or to pause long enough for the reader to successfully get lock the mutex - unless you make it.

The second is that your reader is anyway incorrect:

```
void read() {
    while (true) {
        unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
        cond.wait(locker);
        if (!que.empty()) {
            cout << que.front() << endl;
            que.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you get one "wakeup event" per element pushed onto the queue, because it consumes exactly one element per wakeup. But that's *not* how condition variables work.

It's entirely possible for this sequence to happen:

1. publisher adds item 1

   - publisher signals condvar
2. publisher adds item 2

   - publisher signals condvar
3. reader wakes from condvar wait

   - reader consumes item 1

In this case the publisher will add 100 items, and signal 100 times, but the reader will only wake 99 times and therefore consume at most 99 items.

The correct code should be something like this:

```
void read() {
    unique_lock<mutex> locker(m);
    while (true) {
        // don't wait if we don't have to
        while (que.empty()) {
            cond.wait(locker);
        }
        // consume everything we can
        while (!que.empty()) {
            cout << que.front() << endl;
            que.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Using the predicate achieves roughly the same thing (I just wrote all the logic out explicitly for clarity) - the second `while` isn't there in your edit, but looping round and skipping the first while is a slightly more expensive way to get the same behaviour.

Also, there's no need to thrash the mutex on every iteration - the condition variable already (un)locks it as required.

Comment: I am a little bit bothered by that `que.empty()` check surrounding `cond.wait`. My concern is that you are looking at `que` without locking it first. It seems harmless since the worse thing that seems to be possible is that an element is added while checking. However, I can't seem to shake the feeling that something bad could happen there.

Comment: The mutex is locked first and stays locked through _all_ the top-level user code in that function. The only thing outside the locked scope is `while(true)`. (It's unlocked and re-locked inside the wait, though).